# Exporting WebBrowser to PDF with userform or in spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, activex, userform

I am implementing a feature to my excel-program that will show me a map (from google maps) of some coordinates. The idea is to be able to export this map with other pages to PDF. It looks like I have two options:

**1)** Inserting a ActiveX "Microsoft Web-Browser" directly in to the worksheet and then having excel export said worksheet to a PDF.

**2)** Inserting a ActiveX "Microsoft Web-Browser" in a userform.

My problem for **1)** is that it doesn't seem to work for newer version of excel (2013>), but it does work for Excel 2007.
The problem with **2)** is that it is hard to export a userform to PDF when you also want 2 different pages from the workbook in the same PDF (I do not know if *userform1.printform* has that feature).

My question is if there is either a way to insert a Web-Browser directly in Excel, **for all versions of excel**, or a way for a macro to export both worksheets and userform in the same PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the legal way number 3) Using the [Google Maps Static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro) to download a map as image to a temporary folder and import that image (dynamically) into your Excel file. Then you can export that Excel file to PDF as usual.

> *The Maps Static API service creates your map based on URL parameters sent through a standard HTTP request and returns the map as an image you can display on your web page.*

This means you can download the image file through a standard HTTP request to your computer and place it into Excel.

I'm pretty sure the ways you try to automate it is against Google's terms of use because automated access of Google's services without using the official API is probably not allowed, no matter if private or commerial use (you might get banned).